# Matlab: find the contour and straighten a nearly rectangular image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have this image:

[image: rectangle]

which is rectangle-like but not exactly. I would like to find rectangular contours and I have tried to use **edge** and **hough** but it doesn't find continuous line. I have also tried to **erode** and **dilate** but it can't erase the difference of one pixel on the horizontal upper most line for example so it still doesn't find the continuous line.

The second part of the problem would be to straighten it.

Another idea I got was to find the **corners** to link them with straight lines but it doesn't work either.

I am sure it shouldn't be complicated but I can't make it.

Any ideas will be welcome!
Cheers

Comment: What were the results using the Hough transform, why didn't that work? Same for corner detection.

Comment: If you just want to rotate it, you can use [imrotate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrotate.html). For your case you could rotate by 1 degree and then check the sum in one of the dimensions. If some consecutive columns have `[120,122,124]` white pixels, you have to rotate more. When you get `[122,122,122]`, your job is done.

Comment: So, @user1270155, did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`regionprops()`**](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) to  find the bounding boxes of the contiguous regions in a binary image:

```
img = imread('rect.jpg');
bw = im2bw(img);

% find both black and white regions
stats = [regionprops(bw); regionprops(not(bw))]

% show the image and draw the detected rectangles on it
imshow(bw); 
hold on;

for i = 1:numel(stats)
    rectangle('Position', stats(i).BoundingBox, ...
    'Linewidth', 3, 'EdgeColor', 'r', 'LineStyle', '--');
end
```

Result:

[image: image with rects drawn on it]

Answer (score 1):

To find contour, you can do edge detection and then thicken the line. You might not get a straight line only with morphological operations since your figure is like that. Morphological operations will apply the same effect to entire image. Also, edge detection will not give a straight line.

As far as finding a straight line, I think the problem falls under the category of finding the minimum bounding rectangle. But if the terminology `straight` means `parallel to X-Y axis` then answer by `Junuxx` should work. Minimum bounding rectangle tightly adheres to the image but not necessarily parallel to X-Y axis. You can find an implementation of that algorithm [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34767-a-suite-of-minimal-bounding-objects/content/MinBoundSuite/minboundrect.m). To find the minimum bounding rectangle of above image, first use `remove` from `bwmorph` and then give that point set as input to the minimum bounding rectangle algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the values of "black" and "white", you can find the edges by drawing a contour at the midway point - so if black = 0 and white = 1, draw a contour at 0.5. You can do this for example with the following:

```
img = zeros(500, 500);
img(200:300, 200:300) = 1;
img(210:290, 210:290) = 0;
img = imrotate(img, 3);
c = contourc(img, 0.5*[1 1]); % repeat 0.5 to be interpreted as value of contour
```

The coordinates of the contours are now in c. You can also plot the contour with

```
contour(img, 0.5*[1 1]);
```

When you look at `c`, you can figure out where the corners are; once you know that, you can do a projective transformation using `imtransform` which is in the image processing toolbox.

I hope these two things will get you going...

Comment: Thank you for your help. It does help although computing c in that way gives outlyers (some x coordinates are at 0.5). But imtransform was of great help.

Comment: The outliers are almost like a "starting point" of the contour. As though you are using an Etch-a-Sketch and your "pen" is starting at the wrong place. I have seen them - they are pretty easy to find (for example if you use `abs(diff())` they will correspond to very big numbers). Glad `imtransform` helped.